# Clicking reset button on VBA form results in error

Tags: vba

Each time I click on the **Reset** button on my form. I get the following error message:

```
Run-Time error '380':
Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value.
```

I've tried to debug the code and the error seems to be coming from these lines:

```
cbo_prefRoom1.Value = "No preference"
cbo_prefRoom2.Value = "No preference"
cbo_prefRoom3.Value = "No preference"
```

What could be causing this error? I've checked the form and the I've referenced the combobox in particular correctly.

Here is the code for the entire function:

```
Private Sub btn_Reset_Click()

    ' Reset form
    Dim ctl As msforms.Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctl.Text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                ctl.ListIndex = -1
        End Select
    Next ctl

    Me.cbo_deptCode = "CO - Computer Science"

    ' Set default value for checkbox
    Me.chk_week1.Value = True
    Me.chk_week2.Value = True
    Me.chk_week3.Value = True
    Me.chk_week4.Value = True
    Me.chk_week5.Value = True
    Me.chk_week6.Value = True
    Me.chk_week7.Value = True
    Me.chk_week8.Value = True
    Me.chk_week9.Value = True
    Me.chk_week10.Value = True
    Me.chk_week11.Value = True

    ' Set default value for round
    Me.cbo_rounds = "Priority"

    ' Set default value for semester
    Me.cbo_semester = "1"

     ' Set default value for priority
    priority_y.Value = 1

    ' Set default value for lectureStyle
    lecturestyle_trad = 1

    ' Set default value from roomStructure
    rs_Tiered = 1

    ' Set default value for fac1,fac2,fac3
    cbo_fac1.Value = "No preference"
    cbo_fac2.Value = "No preference"
    cbo_fac3.Value = "No preference"

    ' Set default value for prefRoom1,prefRoom2,prefRoom3
    cbo_prefRoom1.Value = "No preference"
    cbo_prefRoom2.Value = "No preference"
    cbo_prefRoom3.Value = "No preference"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the combobox's `Style` set to `fmListStyleDropDown` and "No Preference" isn't an item in the combobox, you'll get this error.